# How do I mock an imported object in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

So, I'm working my way through learning Jest, and in a current Aurelia project, the internal working of the generated `main.js` script imports a configuration object (environment). Note this code is all as-generated.

```
// main.js
import environment from './environment';
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

// remove out if you don't want a Promise polyfill (remove also from webpack.config.js)
Bluebird.config({ warnings: { wForgottenReturn: false } });

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'));

  // Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  // aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-animator-css'));
  // if the css animator is enabled, add swap-order="after" to all router-view elements

  // Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  // aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-html-import-template-loader'));

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
  }

  return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

The `environment` object is just holding a couple simple values:

```
export default {
  debug: true,
  testing: true
};
```

Now, when I want to test the branching logic in main.js, I want to be able to flip those booleans to ensure they do or don't execute the config changes as appropriate:

```
import {configure} from '../../src/main';
import environment from '../../src/environment';
/* later... */
  describe('when the environment is not set to debug', () => {
    environment.debug = false;
    it('should not configure development logging', () => {
      configure(aureliaMock);
      expect(aureliaMock.use.developmentLogging.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    });
  });
```

This does not work, as the version of `environment` being checked inside the `configure()` function still has the values in the source module.  I recognize that `environment` in this case is my local value, but what I don't know is how to affect the instance of `environment` that's being checked.

I tried using the `jest.mock()` syntax you'd use with an ES6 class constructor, but that doesn't work either.  I will probably change the `configure()` signature to accept an `environment` for testing, but before doing so I wanted to see if there's a way to do this via mocks first.

Comment: hmm..that should work.  I've got a simplified version running in my environment.  Have you confirmed that `environment.debug` is `true` and that you're not picking up earlier calls on `aureliaMock.use.developmentLogging()`?  (maybe use [`mockClear()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear))

Comment: Yeah, I didn't show it here but I am using mockClear to reset the state on all my mocks in a beforeEach.